# How to select polymer component using protractor

Tags: angular, polymer, protractor

Hi following is my html

```
    <div class="ng-scope" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Todos">
<nd-uber-bar class="ng-isolate-scope" title="Title" subtitle="subtitle">
<nd-drawer-panel id="ndDrawerPanel" class="style-scope nd-uber-bar x-scope nd-drawer-panel-0" force-narrow="" disable-swipe="" style="touch-action: auto;" narrow="" selected="drawer">
```

I want to validate selected="drawer" which is polymer component using protractor

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting the `selected` attribute of an element:

```
var polymerPanel = $('#ndDrawerPanel');
expect(polymerPanel.getAttribute("selected")).toEqual("drawer");
```

Comment: @AbbasALI okay, what do you mean by "not working"? Symptoms?

Comment: it saying css not found , we need some other work around

Comment: @AbbasALI ah, my bad, had a missing `#` there, fixed.

Comment: getting this error  "Expected 'true' to equal 'drawer'  what coud be issue?

Comment: any update on it , please confirm , i am getting true not the value